# Open a webpage using SSRS report textbox

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS report where in i need to open a webpage on click of textbox inside table. I have tried with following code in textbox properties -> Action -> GotoURl.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://localhost:53999/login.aspx','_blank'))"
```

In Preview window if I click on textbox no action happens!
Please help me!! Any other setting need to be done to open a webpage in new window?

Comment: It won't work in the preview window (because it's not a web page). It will only work when rendered in a browser - i.e. deployed then run from the web browser. It won't work when rendered to PDF/Excel etc.

Comment: Yes it is!! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can execute code like that, try just using the actual URL http://localhost:53999/login.aspx